Gitea returns me error when trying to git clone a repusitory using public domain name, but everything is fine with private IP
I recently installed Gitea, the self-hosted Git system, which worked fine, until I exposed it to the internet, and now it has a new domain, I can access the website of Gitea from my new domain, but I can't git clone the repository from the site, then I tried again with my private IP and it worked well somehow, and I was able to git clone the repository from the same Gitea site, with the only difference of accessing it inside my network.
I could not find any information on internet, but when tried to use AI to solve the problem it recommended me to change some values in the app.ini file, but even after all of the suggested modifications to app.ini it did not work. Is there anyone who struggled with that?
This image shows the thing that I am experiencing, I am able to clone the repo privately, but trying to clone it with domain name causes an error:


Please don't post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.
